# Chocolatey: Install-ChocolateyPackage arguments

Tags: chocolatey

[Install-ChocolateyPackage](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-package) commands show often a `softwareName`, which is not explicitly documented:

```
$packageName= 'bob'
$toolsDir   = "$(Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$url        = 'https://somewhere.com/file.msi'
$url64      = 'https://somewhere.com/file-x64.msi'

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName   = $packageName
  fileType      = 'msi'
  url           = $url
  url64bit      = $url64
  silentArgs    = "/qn /norestart"
  validExitCodes= @(0, 3010, 1641)
  softwareName  = 'Bob*'
  checksum      = '12345'
  checksumType  = 'sha256'
  checksum64    = '123356'
  checksumType64= 'sha256'
}

Install-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs
```

Sometimes, like above, it adds a  wildcard to the package name. Sometimes it works like a long package name:

```
$packageName = 'Firefox'
$softwareName = 'Mozilla Firefox'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very nice that you saw that. The argument is not in `Install-ChocolateyPackage` yet, thus why it is not documented (there is nothing to document at this time).

The plans are to have both `SoftwareName` and `SoftwareVersion` (both fuzzy searches) as part of the parameters so that if the software is found installed, Chocolatey won't try to run the installer again. It's not there yet, but we introduced an unused variable into the output from the default template (`choco new`).

We do have an announce list, https://groups.google.com/group/chocolatey-announce where we announce new releases across all parts of Chocolatey. Subscribe there to learn when that will become available.